# drawing on the map and count pushpin angular js

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I try use google map in my app. Is there possible drawing on the google map and count pushpin inside.
For Example I mark an area and somewhere returns the number of selected clients, for example.Map like below.

[image]

This is how I show a data :

This is my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Client} from 'src/models/client';
import { ClientService } from '../clientService';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients-on-map',
  templateUrl: './clients-on-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients-on-map.component.css']
})
export class ClientsOnMapComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'WhiteSpaceMapWebUI';
  lat : number = 52.237049;
  lng : number = 21.017532;

 clientList : Array<Client>;



  constructor(private client : ClientService){}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getClients();
  }


  getClients(){
    this.client.getClients().subscribe(clients => this.clientList = clients) ;};

  }
```

And my ClientService :

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

    private url : string = '/api/Client';

    constructor(private http : HttpClient){}
    
      getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
        return this.http.get<Client[]>(this.url);
       }
}
```

Comment: you may find this youtube video helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWn9iBYiJrk

Comment: So first of all, how are you displaying those markers? When you receive a response from using Maps API, you should be able to count them. So please provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates your issue. You can use stackBlitz to do this.